# Чем осложнены данные предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, вводные-слова

> 1. «Пророк несбывшихся чудес», Есенин так и не примкнул к революции, а от родной деревни, давно потерявший прежнюю духовную основу,
>      безнадежно далеко отошел.
> 2. Услышь меня, хорошая, услышь меня, красивая, заря моя вечерняя, любовь неугасимая!

Можно ли сказать что оно осложнено однородными членами предложения?

> 3.Мы, то есть студенты, обменялись многозначительными взглядами.

Согласованное уточняющее приложение  или пояснительная конструкция, или...?

Comment: ...от деревни какой?-давно потерявшЕй...

Comment: Здесь возможны варианты: 1) от деревни, давно потерявшей... и 2) Есенин, давно потерявший... === В Сети встречаются оба варианта.

Comment: А по-моему, все же правилен ответ Людмилы. Разве можно потерять духовную основу от деревни?

Comment: А разве нельзя? Впрочем, спросите лучше у Марии Максимовой -- это выдержка из её текста приведена в задании. См. http://www.bsu.by/Cache/pdf/248973.pdf

Answer (score 1):

В первом примере предложение осложнено обособленным приложением **«Пророк несбывшихся чудес»** и обособленным причастным оборотом - **«давно потерявший прежнюю духовную основу».**

Во втором предложении - однородные обращения **"хорошая,красивая, заря моя вечерняя, любовь неугасимая!"**

В примере третьем пояснительная конструкция: обозначается одно и то же понятие другими словами, о чем свидетельствует пояснительный союз **«то есть».**

Answer (score 0):

> Чем осложнены данные предложения?

===

***1. «Пророк несбывшихся чудес», Есенин так и не примкнул к революции, а от родной деревни, давно потерявший прежнюю духовную основу, безнадежно далеко отошел.***

*(Есенин) **не примкнул, отошел*** --  однородные сказуемые;

***«Пророк несбывшихся чудес»***, (Есенин) -- обособленное приложение;

*(Есенин), **давно потерявший прежнюю духовную основу***  -- обособленное несогласованное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом.

===

***2. Услышь меня, хорошая, услышь меня, красивая, заря моя вечерняя, любовь неугасимая!***

По-моему, имеем **бессоюзное сложное предложение**.

Первая часть осложнена обращением:

*Услышь меня, **хорошая**.*

Вторая -- рядом однородных обращений:

*услышь меня, **красивая, заря моя вечерняя, любовь неугасимая!***

===

***3. Мы, то есть студенты, обменялись многозначительными взглядами.***

*(Мы), **то есть студенты*** -- пояснительная конструкция.